# How to connect two circles where each is in a Pane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I was wondering if someone could give me a tip on connecting two nodes where each is in a separate Pane. I'm doing a creative programming project where the goal is to demonstrate graph algorithms visually. this is my progress so far. Here are pictures along with a description of what is happening :

Create two CircleNodes (CircleNodes are a class that extends group. They consist of a Circle and a label added to a Pane), A and B, via a double click

[image]

Start a full drag line with source on A. The dragged line is just a visual for the user

[image]

End the drag by releasing on B and creating a two LinkNode from A to B and B to A

[image]

Create a LinkNode (just a class that extends group and consists of a line and distance() function) from A to B so that the Nodes can link together.

The problem is that, when creating a LinkNode by getting the centerX and centerY of the Circle in the Pane, the line in the LinkNode is an different position from the intented one. I'm fairly sure the problem is not being able to get circle coordinates inside the Pane.

CircleNode (DraggedLine is mostly irrelevant, but it may be causing issues):

```
    class CircleNode extends Pane {
    //Node will have fixed height and width
    private final static int R = 20;
    //Node will have a name so that it can be found
    private String name;
    private DraggedLine draggedLine;
    private double x, y;
    private Circle circle;
    private Pane layout;
    //collection of colors which the circle can be
    CircleNode(double x, double y, String name){
        layout = new StackPane();
        Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.VIOLET};
        int randColorIndex = (int)(Math.random() * colors.length);
        Label label = new Label(name);
        this.name = name;
        circle = new Circle(R);
        circle.setFill(colors[randColorIndex]);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        setTranslateX(x);
        setTranslateY(y);
        //lost on what to do here
        //layout.setTranslateX(x);
        //layout.setTranslateY(y);
        //circle.setCenterX(x);
        //circle.setCenterY(y);
        //circle.setLayoutX(x);
        //circle.setLayoutY(y);
        this.createLinkHandler();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(circle, label);
        getChildren().add(layout);
        display();
    }

    private void createLinkHandler(){
        this.setOnDragDetected(de -> {
            this.startFullDrag();
            System.out.println("Full drag started on " + ((CircleNode)de.getSource()).getName());
            //System.out.println("Drag detected and Full drag started");
            //Line line = drawLine(de.get)
            //LinkNode temp_link = new LinkNode(this.getTranslateX(), this.getTranslateY(), de.getX(), de.getY()) );
        });
        this.setOnMouseDragged(de -> {
            this.getChildren().remove(draggedLine);
            draggedLine = new DraggedLine(circle.getLayoutX(), circle.getLayoutY(), de.getX(), de.getY());
            this.getChildren().add(draggedLine);
        });
        this.setOnMouseDragReleased(de -> {
            this.getChildren().remove(draggedLine);
            CircleNode source = (CircleNode)de.getGestureSource();
            if(de.getGestureSource() == null){
                System.out.println("Failed to create link\nNo CircleNode found to complete the drag");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Drag started on " + source.getName() + " and ended on: " + this.name);
            this.getChildren().add(new LinkNode(source, this));
            source.getChildren().add(new LinkNode(this, source));

            this.getChildren().remove(draggedLine);
        });        
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Layout x, y: " + layout.getTranslateX() + ", " + layout.getTranslateY() );
        System.out.println("Circle x, y:  " + circle.getCenterX() + ", " + circle.getCenterY());
        System.out.println("Translate x, y: " + getTranslateX() + ", " + getTranslateY());
    }

    public String getName(){ return name; }

    public Circle getCircle(){ return circle;}

    public Pane getLayout(){ return layout;}

    public void removeDraggedLine(){if(draggedLine != null) getChildren().remove(draggedLine);}

    private static Line drawLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        return new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }


    }

    class DraggedLine extends Group{
    private Line line;

    DraggedLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        getChildren().add(line);
    }

    public void drawLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        this.line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    }

LinkNode:

    class LinkNode extends Group {
    private double distance;
    private CircleNode start, end;
    private Line line;

    LinkNode(CircleNode start, CircleNode end){
        if(start.getName().equals(end.getName())){
            System.out.println("You can't connect a circle node to itself");
            return;
        }
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        //this is part causing problems:
        //Circle c1 = start.getCircle(), c2 = end.getCircle();
        //double x1 = c1.getCenterX(), y1= c1.getCenterY(), x2 = c2.getCenterX(), y2 = c2.getCenterY();
        //double x1 = c1.getCenterX(), y1= c1.getCenterY(), x2 = c2.getCenterX(), y2 = c2.getCenterY();
        double x1 = start.getTranslateX(), y1= start.getTranslateY(), x2 = end.getTranslateX(), y2= start.getTranslateY();
        distance = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        line.setStroke(Color.MIDNIGHTBLUE);
        line.setStrokeWidth(3);
        getChildren().add(line);
        System.out.println(toString());
        System.out.println("Coordinate start: " + x1 + ", " + y1 +"\nCoordinate end: " + x2 + ", " + y2);
        start.removeDraggedLine();
        end.removeDraggedLine();
    }

    public String toString(){ return start.getName() + "->" + end.getName() + "\nDistance: " + distance;}

    private static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2,double  y2){
        return Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }

    public double getDistance(){
        return distance;
    }

    public Line getLine(){
        return line;
    }

    public CircleNode getStart(){
        return start;
    }

    public CircleNode getEnd(){
        return end;
    }
}
```

Edit:
I was able to solve the problem by just avoiding using a pane altogether but this way I can't display the Node's name. New pictures:

[Create two Nodes, A and B with their names unable to be displayed because they are in a group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf8l5.png)
[Start a drag on one and release a Drag on the other to create a link between the two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjiDq.png)
[Do the same thing with another node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82vF9.png)

```
class CircleNode extends Group{
    private String name;
    private double x, y;
    private Circle circle;
    private Line draggedLine;
    private Pane layout;
    private static final int R = 15;

    public CircleNode(double x, double y, String name){
        //layout = new Pane();
        //layout.getChildren().add(label);
        this.name = name;
        circle = new Circle(x, y, R);
        Label label = new Label(name, circle);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        circle.setFill(selectColor());
        circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        this.createLinkHandler();
        getChildren().addAll(circle);
    }

    private void createLinkHandler(){
        this.setOnDragDetected(de -> {
            this.startFullDrag();
           // draggedLine = new Line(x, y, de.getX(), de.getY());
            System.out.println("Full drag started on " + ((CircleNode)de.getSource()).name);
            //System.out.println("Drag detected and Full drag started");
            //Line line = drawLine(de.get)
            //LinkNode temp_link = new LinkNode(this.getTranslateX(), this.getTranslateY(), de.getX(), de.getY()) );
        });

        this.setOnMouseDragged(de -> {
            //getChildren().remove(draggedLine);
            //draggedLine = new Line(x, y, de.getX(), de.getY());
            //getChildren().add(draggedLine);
        });

        this.setOnMouseDragReleased(de -> {
            System.out.println("Full drag ended on: " + this.name);
            //getChildren().remove(draggedLine);
            CircleNode source = (CircleNode)de.getGestureSource();
            if(de.getGestureSource() == null){
                System.out.println("Failed to create link, No CircleNode found to complete the drag");
                return;
            }
            //System.out.println("Drag started on " + source.name + " and ended on: " + this.name);
            this.getChildren().add(new LinkNode(source, this));
            source.getChildren().add(new LinkNode(this, source));
        });
    }

    public Color selectColor(){
        Color[] colors = {Color.VIOLET, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY, Color.GOLD, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUEVIOLET, Color.YELLOW};
        return colors[(int)(Math.random() * (colors.length - 1 - 1) + 1)];
    }

    public Circle getCircle(){
        return circle;
    }
}

class LinkNode extends Group{
    private Line line;
    private CircleNode start, end;
    private double distance;
    public LinkNode(CircleNode start, CircleNode end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        double x1 = start.getCircle().getCenterX(), y1 = start.getCircle().getCenterY(), x2 = end.getCircle().getCenterX(),
                y2 = end.getCircle().getCenterY();
        line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        this.distance = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        getChildren().add(line);
    }

    public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2) );
    }
}
```

Comment: `StackPane` positions the children according to the alignment. By default, it's centering the children. The simplest solution is not using `StackPane`, but `Pane` which does not change the position of children on it's own.

Comment: Hello Fabian, I fixed the code to use Pane instead of StackPane but the problem persists. Could you give me some advice as to how you would go about this?

Comment: If you want to change `layout` to a `Pane` you need to change:  `layout = new StackPane()`

Comment: I was able to solve the problem but I had to take out the Pane entirely which is a real bummer because I wanted to display the nodes name as well. If anyone has a solution to the original question I'd be very grateful.